# Minimal Network latency

Tags: networking, routing

Ok guys, I got this on a test about networking in the university. So lets assume ideal conditions for this one:

In Which communication schema the network is expected to have minimal latency in communication between PC1 and PC2

a) PC1 – Switch1 – Switch2 – Switch3 – PC2

b) PC1 – Firewall1 – Router – Firewall2 – PC2

c) PC1 – Router1 – Router2 – Router3 – PC2

d) PC1 – Switch1 – Router – Switch2 – PC2

I personnaly think that each message should travel though the 3 mid-nodes anyway and the less work on packets would make a difference between router and switch. The router's will speed up the connection in more complex environment when you have alternate paths and costs etc. Furthermore adding 3 routers will increase the traffic because the router's have internal protocols and will communicate between each other(RIP, OSPF ) In this simple case should the 3 switches be  the fastest choice.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) would be the logical choice because switches use ASICs (hardware) to do the switching, thus minimizing the latency. Also, Cisco routers have something called Express Forwarding which allows routing to be implemented on ASICs.

I think what determines the lowest latency is the state the communication (whether the CAM tables have been populated on the switches and whether the MAC tables have been populated on the routers).